# Cumulative CPU Time (Time column in the o/p of ps aux command)

Tags: linux, shell-script

What is mean of cumulative CPU Time (Time column in the o/p of `ps aux` command )?
And the difference between 9th and 10th column of output of `ps aux` command?

Answer (score 5):

if you do `man ps` then under the section "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" each header is explained.

> TIME accumulated cpu time, user + system...

i.e. the amount of cpu used so far by the process in minutes:seconds.

> START time the command started...

i.e. the time of day (hours:minutes), or date, the command was started.